# I can't compile Java files after Windows update! (PowerShell replaced Command Prompt.)

Tags: powershell, javac, windows-update

I can't compile any Java programs after PowerShell replaced the Command Prompt in the file menu during a Windows update.  I tried using the same `SET PATH` command that I used with the Command Prompt (`set path = c:\"Program Files"\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin`).  The `java` command worked, but `javac` was not recognized.

After learning how to access the Command Prompt (type "CMD" in the search box in the bottom left corner), I assumed everything would work like normal - but I was mistaken.  The `javac` command SEEMED to work.  It flagged errors when I first tried to compile.  After fixing the errors, I thought I had an error free compile.  It was when I tried to run my "newly compiled" program that I noticed that my new changes were not showing!  I discovered that - in spite of it seeming to compile - no new CLASS files were being created.  (It was the old CLASS files that were being run.)

I was then advised to make sure I was the administrator.  I did - with PowerShell and the Command Prompt - but it made no difference.

I tried reinstalling Java - but that made no difference either.

Here is what happens when I compile as administrator from the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\penny\Java>Set Path=C:\"Program Files"\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin

C:\Users\penny\Java>javac FoodCount.java

C:\Users\penny\Java>java FoodCount
Error: Could not find or load main class FoodCount
```

It compiles (or seems to), but no class file is created.  And, yes, the javac.exe file IS in the bin file:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin>dir javac.exe
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 7040-4F22

 Directory of C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin

07/12/2017  11:48 PM            15,904 javac.exe
               1 File(s)         15,904 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  838,527,008,768 bytes free
```

This is what happened when I used a suggestion from one of the comments for PowerShell.  (This was before I reinstalled Java, so the version is a little different.  After reinstalling, the result was exactly the same.)

```
PS C:\Users\penny\Java> $env:PATH += ';c:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin'
PS C:\Users\penny\Java> javac FoodCount.java
javac : The term 'javac' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ javac FoodCount.java
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (javac:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
PS C:\Users\penny\Java>
```

To sum up, I *seem*  to be able to compile with javac.exe from the command prompt, but no new class file can be found in my directory afterwards.  I cannot get PowerShell to recognize javac.exe at all.

Can anyone tell me what is going on?  I think there must be something going on with the permissions, but being administrator doesn't seem to be enough.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `set` is an alias for the `Set-Variable` cmdlet in PowerShell, to which you must pass the variable name and the value as separate arguments (`Set-Variable <name> <value>`). By contrast, if you do something like `set path=c:\"Program Files"\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin`, you'll get an uninitialized variable literally named `path=c:\"Program Files"\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin` (If you put spaces around the `=`, as currently in your question, you'd get a syntax error).

Comment: Aside from it not being a good idea to _replace_ the existing `PATH` value, you need to tell PowerShell that you want to modify an _environment_ variable as opposed to a PowerShell variable, so what you're looking for is something like `$env:PATH += ';c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin'`

Comment: Thank you for your comments!  Obviously, I need to study PowerShell.  (I assumed at first it was just an updated version of the old command prompt.)  I've noticed the "java" command works without any kind of PATH statement or value in both environments (command prompt and PowerShell).  I just tried your suggested PATH statement, but nothing changed.  The output is below:

Comment: PS C:\Users\penny\Java> $env:PATH += ';c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin'
PS C:\Users\penny\Java> javac FoodCount.java
javac : The term 'javac' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ javac FoodCount.java
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (javac:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\penny\Java>

Comment: If you want the `Command Prompt` restored to your context and `win+x` menu, see [**Restoring Command Prompt after Creators Update**](https://mspoweruser.com/how-to-replace-powershell-with-command-prompt-on-file-explorers-context-menu-in-windows-10/)

Comment: Please verify that there actually is a `javac.exe` located in `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin`.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidC.Rankin.  I'm a little scared to mess with the Registry Editor, but I may try it.  Of course I would prefer having the Command Prompt as the default, but as long as I can get to it by typing "CMD" in the search box, that's good enough.  What bothers me is that even when I open the command prompt as the administrator, no class files are created when I compile.  See my output below:

Comment: C:\Users\penny\Java>Set Path=C:\"Program Files"\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin

C:\Users\penny\Java>javac FoodCount.java

C:\Users\penny\Java>java FoodCount
Error: Could not find or load main class FoodCount

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, thanks for your comment and for making my post look better!  javac.exe is there!

Comment: @Penny Another good link (I prefer the rename technique) is [**How to put "Command Window Here" back in Right-click Context Menu**](https://www.howtogeek.com/302408/how-to-put-open-command-window-here-back-on-the-windows-right-click-menu/) You need not be scared of `regedit`. A simple failsafe is to backup a key before you change it (simply right-click the key, or branch holding the key) and choose `export` to save the current settings as a `.reg` file. Then make your changes. If you want to go back to the default, just double-click your saved `.reg` file. Simple.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidC.Rankin!

Answer (score 0):

I think Windows fixed this "bug" with another automatic update/patch!

When I tried compiling from the command prompt today, it worked!  A class file was saved and I was able to run it.  Yesterday, the compiler (javac.exe) *seemed* to work from the command prompt, but no new class file was created.  I don't know why it would behave differently today - unless a Windows update fixed the problem.

I still can't get javac.exe to run in PowerShell, but I don't know what I am doing there.

If anyone else has this problem, my advice is PATIENCE.  If you wait, it may go away!